# Deploying UDF (User defined functions) to SSAS using ADOMD.NET

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx, adomd.net, data-cube

I'm very new to this and kind of confused as to how I should setup my project in Visual Studio (2022) and how to deploy UDFs and Stored Procedures to a SSAS instance.

I already have a solution with a SSAS data cube project. The cube is deployed and working properly. I also have a WinForms .Net project in the same solution. I managed to add, to the latter project, the reference letting me access the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer` namespace and have written a function that would filter a set using an expression.

So here it is: How do I deploy this function such that it will be available through an MDX Query on my cube?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe UDFs or Stored Procedures can be deployed into the cube itself.

If you have a data access layer in your `WPF` project then you could effectively write the equivalent of Dynamic-SQL but for `MDX` in that data access layer, which would make use of the results of the UDFs and Stored Procedures.